# Question about how to prove this set S is convex

Tags: calculus

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMcVb.png)

The set $S$ is defined as on the above image, how can we prove that S is a convex set?

$S$ is defined as $$S = \{(x_1,x_2,x_3, ...., x_n) : (x_1/a_1)^2 + (x_2/a_2)^2 + ... + (x_n/a_n)^2 \leq 1\}$$ where $a_1,a_2,..., a_n$ can be any nonzero numbers.

Comment: Please tell us more.  Can you include the definition of $S$ directly in the post?  Also,  it would be advised to include the definition of a convex set that you've learned, and your thoughts on how that applies to set $S$.

Comment: What is the set $S$?  I'd rather see an attempt to include it in your post (even if not formatted nicely) than have to chase links.  If you don't have the time to even attempt to do so, ....

Comment: S is { (x1,x2,x3,...,xn) : (x1/a1)^2 + (x2/a2)^2 + ... + (xn / an)^2 <= 1}, where a1, a2, ... , an can be any nonzero number

Comment: Thanks for the work in including the  question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x,y\in S$. Namely, 
$$ \frac{x_1^2}{a_1^2}+\frac{x_2^2}{a_2^2}+\cdots+\frac{x_n^2}{a_n^2}\le1 $$
and
$$ \frac{y_1^2}{a_1^2}+\frac{y_2^2}{a_2^2}+\cdots+\frac{y_n^2}{a_n^2}\le1 $$
By using the following inequality 
$$ (\frac{a+b}{2})^2\le\frac{a^2}{2}+\frac{b^2}{2} $$
one has
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\frac{(\frac{x_1+y_1}{2})^2}{a_1^2}+\frac{(\frac{x_2+y_2}{2})^2}{a_2^2}+\cdots+\frac{(\frac{x_n+y_n}{2})^2}{a_n^2} \\
&\le&\frac12(\frac{x_1^2}{a_1^2}+\frac{x_2^2}{a_2^2}+\cdots+\frac{x_n^2}{a_n^2})+\frac12(\frac{y_1^2}{a_1^2}+\frac{y_2^2}{a_2^2}+\cdots+\frac{y_n^2}{a_n^2})\\
&\le&\frac12+\frac12\\
&=&1
\end{eqnarray}
namely, $\frac{x+y}{2}\in S$. So $S$ is convex.

Answer (score 0):

It is a sublevel set of a convex function thus convex.